# Adjusting a <div> width taking a scrollbar into account

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have two `div` elements; one of them with a scrollbar on the side:

```
+-------------+ ?
|  div A      | ?
+-------------+ ?
|             |^|
|             | |
|             | |
|   div B     |=|
|             | |
+-------------|v|
```

I want `div A` to be exactly as wide as `div B` *minus* the width of its scrollbar. The scrollbar is always there (by explicit `overflow: scroll`). OTOH `div A` is of fixed height and does not need scrolling. I want the client areas of `div A` and `div B` to be aligned.

I could probably make an artificial scrollbar control using JS. If possible, I'd prefer a CSS-based, native-looking solution, though.

I could put a separate piece of padding where the `?` on the picture are, if I somehow knew what the platform-dependent width of the scrollbar is.

Is there a way to achieve this, at least in modern browsers?

Comment: You should really make an attempt at this with a **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)**

Comment: Probably you'll be safe if you go with a fixed width for all 3 major browsers on desktop http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php

Comment: Is there a problem if it is a js solution?

Comment: you could use an extra element to hold the scrollbar  and a safe padding value to keep it aside far enough: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyrst

Comment: @LcSalazar: a JS solution would be OK, while a CSS would be extra nice.

Comment: @GCyrillus: the padding solution is nice, except for the magical constant for the scrollbar width. It's much better than nothing, though; thanks.

Comment: thanks, i made an answer of it and what i think about it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility uses only css, and it is very reliable.

On the top div, create a inner div to hold the content, and a hidden pseudo `:after` element to generate the scrollbar's width. I've used a `display: table` aligment to keep inline, but other techniques will do as well:

Works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/4gu5mkzy/1/

```
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: table;
}

#top:after {
    display: table-cell;
    content: "";
    overflow-y: scroll;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    background: yellow;
}

<div id="top">
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, CSS alone will not do it unless you adapt you HTML and go for a little compromise.

**Not a pixel perfect** solution, but since scollbar are not alike from a browser to another ...

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyrst)**

HTML test:

```
<div class="ab">A</div>
<div class="sc">
  <div class="ab">B</div>
</div>
```

CSS test:

```
.ab {
  width:200px;
  background-color:gray;
}
.sc {
  width:200px;
  padding-right:1.1em;
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.sc .ab { 
  height:200px;/*demo purpose */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Javascript simple function to calculate the width of the scrollbar. Just set a div width `overflow: scroll` and an inner div, and subtract their `offsetWidth`:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLjkr9ce/1/

HTML:

```
<div id='outer-div'>
    <div id='inner-div'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer-div {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
var ow = document.getElementById("outer-div").offsetWidth;
var iw = document.getElementById("inner-div").offsetWidth;

alert(ow - iw); //Scrollbar's rendered width
```

Then set this value as the padding.

**BUT**

that may be pointless, since almost all (if not all) major browsers have a 17px width scrollbar:

See [**this article with the Test Results**](http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php)

> **Chrome** v34 17 pixels
>
> **Internet Explorer**  v11 17 pixels
>
> **Internet Explorer**  v10 17 pixels
>
> **Firefox**    v29 17 pixels
>
> **Firefox**    v28 17 pixels

So basically, I believe a simple `padding` of 17px might be enough, though the article states that is a common practice to use a 20px basis.

Comment: There are OSX and the default Ubuntu setup, both pretty widespread among the target audience of the page in question. In both of them the scrollbar is initially a very narrow band with a scroller control popping up on mouse-over.